# Going out of bounds in an AVX2 register

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, simd, avx2

Say I have this piece of code:

```
__m256i i1, i2, i3;
memcpy(&i1, p + offsets[0], n);
memcpy(&i2, p + offsets[1], n);
memcpy(&i3, p + offsets[2], n);

// etc
```

And `n` is set greater than 32.

I know bad things will happen to me - but I've not actually seen this piece of code segfault. I know that clang's address sanitizer complains of stack corruption, and checking the assembly reveals it has not optimised out the call to `memcpy`. What are the guarantees (if any) provided by Intel/C++?

Comment: Undefined behavior. So no guarantees by anything.

Comment: You break the language rules (UB), you get to keep the pieces. No guarantees *what so ever*.

Comment: That's irrelevant to registers. Registers don't have addresses only names. When you take address of __m256i variable and pass it to e.g. memcpy, compiler will store the register on the stack if needed, and use address from the stack.

Comment: Vector types are not YMM registers any more than `int` is an integer register.  It has an address just like any other C++ variable.  If you write code that can't or doesn't optimize the variable into a register, it will actually be stored in memory.  In practice you could be stepping on some stack memory for another variable, or the return address.  If it doesn't crash, maybe you just hit padding (e.g. for alignment) on the stack.